# What does "efficiency" in a tool do?

Tags: stardew-valley

When leveling up one of your skills in Stardew Valley, you are frequently told that you have gained efficiency in using a particular tool. For example, gaining a level in farming gave me +1 to Watering Can and Hoe efficiency.

What do these actually do? They don't appear to make the tools any more effective. Am I correct in assuming that it has something to do with energy usage (the only other thing I can think of related to tool use)?

Comment: bleh. can't believe i missed that (doesn't actually have the term "stardew valley" in the question....)

Comment: You can filter with the [tag:stardew-valley] tag.

Comment: yeah, I know, I just didn't think of it. I've added the phrase here in case others make my mistake :)